# Javascript doesn't call the page URL so it doesn't refresh to display the correct information

Tags: javascript, css

I have set up javascript menu on a wordpress site I am currently working on

http://www.ogormanconstruction.co.uk/

I have created twelve options within the menu but when you click on any of them it doesn't seem to move from the front page although the page URL changes accordingly

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/jMaster.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/supersleight.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/hashchange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/actions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/tinyscroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27552031-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://include.reinvigorate.net/re_.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                reinvigorate.track("rq7v9-32hz0870n7");
            } catch (err) { }
        </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <hgroup>
            <div class="line"></div>
                <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>

            </hgroup>

            <?php
                // Check to see if the header image has been removed
                $header_image = get_header_image();
                if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    // The header image
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() &&
                            has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$fldIsPublished" id="ctl00_fldIsPublished" />

        <div id="header">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="clearfix">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div id="menuNav"><a href="#" class="openNav">Menu</a></div>
                        <ul class='clearfix'><li><strong>O'Gorman Construction</strong><ul class='clearfix'><li><a href='/about-us'>About Us</a></li><li><a href='/work'>Work</a></li><li><a href='/recruitment'>Recruitment</a></li><li><a href='/contact'>Contact</a></li></ul></li><li><strong>Services</strong><ul class='clearfix'><li><a href='/site-logistics'>Site Logistics</a></li><li><a href='/waste-management'>Waste Management</a></li><li><a href='/security-services'>Security Services</a></li><li><a href='/traffic-management'>Traffic Management</a></li></ul></li><li><strong>&nbsp;</strong><ul><li><a href='/multi-service-gangs'>Multi Service Gangs</a></li><li><a href='/facilities-accomodation'>Facilities & Accomodation</a></li><li><a href='/small-works-maintenance'>Small Works & Maintenance</a></li><li><a href='/catering-services'>Catering Services</a></li></ul></li></ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="/" id="logo"></a>
        </div>

<h2>Work</h2>
<div class="leftCol">
<div class="rightCol gallery">
    <ul id="homeGallery">
<li id="prevControl"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li id="galleryItems">

                    <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a class="projectLink" href='#' alt='Kirschner'></a>
                        <div class="galleryImage"><img src='/wp-content/themes/child/images/1.jpg' /></div>
                        <div class="galleryText"><div class="leftCol noborder" style="text-align: left;"><strong>Basingstoke Treatment Works</strong></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="projectLink" href='#' alt='Loake'></a>
                        <div class="galleryImage"><img src='/wp-content/themes/child/images/2.jpg' /></div>
                        <div class="galleryText"><div class="leftCol noborder" style="text-align: left;"><strong>Project II</strong></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="projectLink" href='#' alt='JTA'></a>
                        <div class="galleryImage"><img src='/wp-content/themes/child/images/3.jpg' /></div>
                        <div class="galleryText"><div class="leftCol noborder" style="text-align: left;"><strong>Project III</strong></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="projectLink" href='#' alt='Umbro'></a>
                        <div class="galleryImage"><img src='/wp-content/themes/child/images/4.jpg' /></div>
                        <div class="galleryText"><div class="leftCol noborder" style="text-align: left;"><strong>Project IV</strong></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="projectLink" href='#' alt='GrooveEffect'></a>
                        <div class="galleryImage"><img src='/wp-content/themes/child/images/5.jpg' /></div>
                        <div class="galleryText"><div class="leftCol noborder" style="text-align: left;"><strong>Project V</strong></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="projectLink" href='#' alt='ohw?'></a>
                        <div class="galleryImage"><img src='/wp-content/themes/child/images/6.jpg' /></div>
                        <div class="galleryText"><div class="leftCol noborder" style="text-align: left;"><strong>Project VI</strong></div></div>
                    </li>

                    </ul>

        </li>

<li id="nextControl"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li id="viewControl"><a href="#">View</a></li>
        <li id="copyright">&copy; O'Gorman Construction</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

    </header><!-- #branding -->

    <div id="main">

<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Showcase.aspx?isLiveContent=true" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/WebResource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/jsdebug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgK/z/SLBgKIvtqEDBhVLjfM03MtZyNTUwnapNYGvfxJ" />
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls([], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>


<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-content/themes/child/scripts/re_.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                reinvigorate.track("rq7v9-32hz0870n7");
            } catch (err) { }
        </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: You need to remove a lot of clutter from your code excerpt so that we can help you.

At first glace, your anchors don't seem to have valid hrefs. They are all "#". There are also no onclick event handlers on them. This is my best guess of where your problem is. Try changing those href="#".

I am not familiar with wordpress, it is possible that you are relying on a script to add them later, but I'm not about to dig through all your scripts to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `window.location.reload();` after the address bar has the new URL in it and it will go to that new URL. I don't know why it's not going to the new URL when you dump it in the address bar, because I didn't go over all of your code to see where/how you're doing it. If you change the way you're setting the `url` to `window.location.href = "http://new.url.com/"` it should actually load the URL immediately.

Comment: caleb was right... your code if very cluttered and hard to read/parse for the relevant bit. This is why I didn't dig through and offer the "best" ideal solution. But if you're just hacking things together and not really trying to become an expert on how it really works, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Sparky - but not for the snark...y. Cut a noob some slack, will ya? I'll do my best to learn all the formatting tricks and etiquette as soon as I can, promise! (perhaps you can answer my next question: how do I send you a message/reply in a case like this without cluttering up a question page?)